# Fast blob downloading

Tags: javascript, streaming, blob

I'm using this code to download files from my web api:

```
function download(name){
    axios.get(api + "?filename="+name, { responseType: 'blob' })
        .then(res => {
            let blob = new Blob([res.data]);
            let a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.href = window.URL.createObjectUrl(blob);
            a.download = name;
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectUrl(url);
            a.remove();
        }
    );
}
```

When downloading small files this code is great, but when downloading large files (for example 400mb)
the code waits for the blob to read the entire content and only then "starts the download" in the chrome download manager, which is very unintuitive to the client.

Is there a way to "stream" the blob to the filesystem? instead of having to wait for the file to completely arrive to my client's RAM and only then show the download in the downloads manager?

**SOLVED**

Instead of downloading the file through axios library, I'm just referring the browser to the download link, since it's just a GET request.

```
function download(name){
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = api + "?filename="+name;
    a.click();
    a.remove();
}
```

Just need to set ContentDisposition header on server side to attachment and also specify a file name since download attribute somewhy does not work with this method.

Also specifying ContentLength will allow the browser to estimate download time

Comment: If you're happy with your own solution, [it's encouraged to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you needed to download the response of a `POST` request or your request needs some kind of advanced authentication, instead of using the `axios` library, you could try using the native `fetch` method.

```
fetch(options)
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    // use blob
  });
```

You can view the full `response` API [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response).